# Getting 404 page while serving the build of the NextJs App while its running fine in the development mode

Tags: reactjs, build, next.js, material-ui, serve

I am pretty new to React/Next JS. So here's my issue. I have purchased a theme and made changes to the config and branding part. Now when I run the app using "yarn dev" and "yarn start", it is working fine. "yarn build" also creates an optimized production build. I wanted to deploy the app locally in my PC and i was trying to learn things through youtube videos. so in one of the videos i found this command ("prod": "next build && serve build") to include in package.json. my package.json file has the following scripts.

"scripts": {
"dev": "next dev",
"build": "next build",
"start": "next start",
"export": "next export",
"lint": "eslint --fix "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"",
"format": "prettier --write "src/**/*.{js,jsx}"",
"prod": "next build && serve build"
},

so when i try with "yarn prod", it is first creating an optimized build and then i get the following output in the vscode terminal

[image]

however if i try to open "http://localhost:3000" in my browser. i get 404 error. but not with "yarn dev" or "yarn start". no error while building the app too.

Comment: I think Next.js does not have anything like "serve build", it is used in create-react-app, you have to use a combination of "next build" and "next start" to run in production mode. refer this https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment

Comment: `next build && next start` is the right way to run the production build of a Next.js app locally. However, if you want to [export the app as static HTML](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export) instead and serve it locally you want to run `next build && next export`. The output of the export is available in the `out` folder by default, so you can serve it locally with `npx serve out`.

Answer (score 0):

Add the **"cleanUrls": true** to "firebase.json" file as below

```
 {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "out",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```